# Extending the attributes inspector in interface builder

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, interface-builder

Is it possible to extend the interface builder's attribute inspector with additional attributes for custom classes inheriting from UIView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at the moment.

Interface Builder allows you to implement custom inspectors for your objects by means of an Interface Builder Plugin. However, IB Kit doesn't currently support making plugins for iPhone OS. Only plugin development for Mac OS is currently supported.

Comment: Is this still the case today?