# iPhone - Creating custom objects for Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, subclass

I am currently subclassing UIView to create custom objects, they work perfectly fine

In interface builder i drag and drop a uiview and I set the class name to my custom view, and in runtime the view will populate according to my code.

QUESTION: Is it possible to make it so that my custom view DRAWS in interface builder, And maybe drag and drop my custom view ?

Comment: according to this other question, you can't on iphone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562655/extending-the-attributes-inspector-in-interface-builder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've researched this myself a while back, as far as i know this is not possible using the iPhone SDK. 
When developing for the Mac SDK you can create your own IB plugins.

Comment: Note that this will be available starting in Xcode 6 when it's released soon (or now, if you have access).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the custom view to the Interface Builder library. Go to File -> Read Class Files... in interface builder, and select your header file to add your item to interface builder's list.

Comment: But that doesn't really draw my View in interface builder