# How to add a downloaded widget to the Objects box in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm writing my first iPhone app.  I needed a custom switch (I want it to say "Male/Female" rather than "On/Off"), and I found [RCSwitch](http://osiris.laya.com/projects/rcswitch/) but I'm having trouble figuring out how to integrate a downloaded widget into my project.  I assume this is a fairly common thing to do, but I can't seem to find any documentation online on how to use a downloaded widget / class.

I have succeeded in adding the code in via Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries.  An RCSwitch directory appears within my project tree, and if I do a diff I see that it has added code related to RCSwitch to the header files.

The problem is getting the widget onto the .storyboard image.  The RCSwitch widget itself does not appear in the "Objects" box -- the one that is by default at the lower right of the screen and includes images of the widgets that you can drag into the storyboard.  Perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

from the [xcode 4 transition guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Xcode4TransitionGuide.pdf#page65) (pg. 65):

> Drag a **custom view object** from the library into the nib file. 
>   After adding the custom view to your nib, select the custom view and
>   assign the correct class to it in the class field under Custom Class
>   in the Identity inspector

Some more resources:

[iphone-creating-custom-objects-for-interface-builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411208/iphone-creating-custom-objects-for-interface-builder)

[Interface Builder Help - Custom Object](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/CustomObject.html)